# Problemas com tipo de array?

Tags: php, postgresql

Estou tendo problemas na formulação de um gráfico.

Tenho basicamente 2 campos: `categorias` e `dados`. Dentro de `categorias`, as informações devem estar dispostas assim: `['categoria 1', 'categoria 2', 'etc']` entre aspas e separadas por vírgula. Já dentro de dados, as informações precisam vir assim: `[dado 1, dado 2, dado 3]` sem aspas.

Preciso pegar ambas informações (`categorias` e `dados`) de um *select* num banco de dados PostgreSQL, porém só obtenho sucesso no campo `dados`, visto que ele não vem nunca separado com aspas. Como posso formatar para incluir as aspas?

Esse é um exemplo de código para os dados:

```
$query="SELECT colunaa from minha tabela";
$output=pg_query($conn,$query);
    ?>
    [<?php while ($result = pg_fetch_array($output)) {?>
                      <?php echo $result["colunaa"]?>,

                    <?php } ?>]
```

Comment: Já tentou fazer `'<?= $result['colunaa'] ?>',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em `PostgreSQL` você pode fazer algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_cores
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    nome TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tb_cores ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 1, 'PRETO' );
INSERT INTO tb_cores ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 2, 'BRANCO' );
INSERT INTO tb_cores ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 3, 'VERMELHO' );
INSERT INTO tb_cores ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 4, 'VERDE' );
INSERT INTO tb_cores ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 5, 'AZUL' );
```

**1)** COM Agregação (separado por vírgulas):

```
SELECT string_agg( nome, ',' ) FROM tb_cores;
```

Saída:

```
|                       string_agg |
|----------------------------------|
| PRETO,BRANCO,VERMELHO,VERDE,AZUL |
```

**2)** COM Agregação (com aspas e separado por vírgulas):

```
SELECT CONCAT( $$'$$, string_agg( nome, $$','$$ ), $$'$$ ) FROM tb_cores;
```

Saída:

```
|                                     concat |
|--------------------------------------------|
| 'PRETO','BRANCO','VERMELHO','VERDE','AZUL' |
```

**3)** SEM agregação, somente aspas:

```
SELECT CONCAT( $$'$$, nome, $$'$$ ) FROM tb_cores;
```

Saída:

```
|     concat |
|------------|
|    'PRETO' |
|   'BRANCO' |
| 'VERMELHO' |
|    'VERDE' |
|     'AZUL' |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/12ca0/5)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode concatenar as aspas:

```
SELECT CONCAT('''', colunaa, '''') from minhatabela
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigada! Funcionou. O problema agora é que no resultado ou o php põe uma vírgula a mais no final, ou não põe vírgula nenhuma.

Comment: Faça `$pulaVirgula = TRUE; echo '['; while ($result ... ) { if ($pulaVirgula) { $pulaVirgula = FALSE; } else { echo ',' } echo "'". $result['colunaa'] . "'"; } echo ']'`

Comment: Se você concatenar no banco de dados, vai criar uma carga desnecessária, num recurso que é não-escalável horizontalmente.

Comment: O código com $pulaVirgula retornou erro